# Align image in center without getting space

Tags: html, css

[image]I want to align the logo at the center in the navigation bar of the page.

This is my code:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="center">
           <a href="home.php"><img src="images/w_logo.gif"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have found this solution online:

```
#center img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

But the problem is that by using display:block property I am getting space around the image which is increasing the height of my navigation bar and I am not being able to remove that space.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet or fiddle for the issue.

Comment: Did you see what is causing the space issue. You might need to check padding and margin (top,bottom).. set all these to 0

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QdF6W/

Comment: @DanPhilip I have added an image. You can get a better understanding of it now. I hope.

Comment: @SrikantSahu There is no padding and margin I have even tried making them 0. No luck.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed Check my answer. My solution will work without any padding and for any image size.

Comment: @SahilDhir I couldn't understand it. is it related to my problem?

Comment: the fiddle has the method to center the image.. Using position attribute of css.

Comment: There is some `padding` or `margin` given to your `a` anchor tag, so due to this the `anchor` tag might be `reflowing` it when it gets `display: block` property. You need to share your current **CSS** Code as well.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your contributions. I have found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/5huhpxuk/

```css
#center img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav {
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 0%
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="center">
      <a href="home.php"><img src="http://zdnet3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2015/09/01/cb834e24-18e7-4f0a-a9bf-4c2917187d3f/83bb139aac01023dbf3e55a3d1789ad8/google-new-logo.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. line-height it is. :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the below. This method sets the `img` to `display: inline-block`, making it an inline element and allowing it to align center when declaring `text-align: center` on the parent element.

```css
/*#center img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}*/

#center {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.nav {
    background: #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bebebe;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="center">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=300%C3%97100&w=300&h=100"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The extra space is probably coming from a rogue browser/vendor style somewhere, suspect elements to look at are the `ul` and `li` which typically come with default `padding` & `margin` rules.
Inspect these elements through your browser developer tool/IDE and have a look at the "box model", or "layout", or "computed styles" depending on the browser you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#center img{
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
ul{margin:0;}
li{padding:0;list-style:none;}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="center"><a href="home.php"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1fp28t1f/)